# How to center 2 elements within a horizontal stackpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a stackpanel with a fixed width.

Within the stackpanel, I have two horizontally aligned elements: a textblock and a textbox.

Is it possible to align these two elements, such they appear side-by-side, but centered within the stackpanel?

Here is my code so far:

```
<StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Width="17cm">
    <TextBlock Text="Invoice Nr:"/>
    <TextBox Width="2cm"  />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

With StackPanel it would be difficult to achieve, but with Grid it can be done by setting HorizontalAlignment and Grid.Column on the children like below:

```
<Grid Width="17cm" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Text="Invoice Nr:"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="2cm"  />

</Grid>
```

Comment: Tried it, but this produces 3 errors: **1.** *The member "ColumnDefinitions" is not recognized or is not accessible.* **2.** *The attachable property 'ColumnDefinitions' was not found in type 'Grid'.* **3.** *The attached property 'Grid.ColumnDefinitions' is not defined on 'StackPanel' or one of its base classes.*

Comment: BTW, I want both elements to be centered (seen as a group). So I assume, the Tag Grid.Column="1" should be set for both elements?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably put the two controls within another container, and then center that container horizontally. Something like this:

```
<StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Width="17cm">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Invoice Nr:"/>
        <TextBox Width="2cm"  />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Tried it, that does not work either. But still thanks, a sub-container is a good hint, perhaps it works with another container.